# Angular Kendo Tabstrip Tab in Custom Component

Tags: angular, kendo-angular-ui

I attempted to enclose a `<kendo-tabstrip-tab>` in a custom Angular component with no success.

For reference, here's the template for the enclosing component:

```html
<kendo-tabstrip-tab (tabSelect)="tabSelect($event)">
    <custom-angular-tab *ngFor="data of allData" [custom1]="data.custom1" [custom2]="data.custom2"></custom-angular-tab>
</kendo-tabstrip-tab>
```

Here's the template for the custom component:

```html
<kendo-tabstrip-tab title="data.title">
  <ng-template kendoTabContent>
     <!-- contents of tab --->
  </ng-template>
</kendo-tabstrip-tab>
```

Unfortunately, when I do this it will not render that tab (view encapsulation issue possibly?). Is there any way to make this work?

I can include the component code if necessary.